# How can I add row of numbers from a file and store average into a double vector?

Tags: java, string, file, vector, double

I need to use a double vector to store an average of a student.

The file I'm reading from is set up like this:

```
2  //num of students
60   //total possible score
John   //name
4 16 9 7 10  //scores
```

So I need to convert the string to a double, add all the ints from the line, divide into an average, then store the average into the double vector.

the code I have so far is:

```
public static String line;
public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("enter the name of your file");
    String filename = in.next();
    FileIn file = new FileIn(filename);

    String firstLine; // String to hold first line which is number of students total in file.
    String secondLine; //String to hold second line which is number of points available 
    
    
    ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();  // holds the students names

    //reads first line of the file. sets that number as the number of students
    firstLine = file.read();
    int numStu = Integer.parseInt(firstLine);
    // Just to test that number is being read correctly.
    System.out.println(numStu + " Number of students");

    //reads the second line of the file. sets that number as the total possible points in a semester
    secondLine = file.read();
    int totalPoints = Integer.parseInt(secondLine);
    // Just to test that number is being read correctly.
    System.out.println(totalPoints + " Total possible points");
    
    
    double avg = 0;
    double[]vector = new double [numStu]; 
    
    readFile(students,numStu,file,vector, avg);
    
    System.out.println(students);
    System.out.println(vector);
}

//puts the names into an arraylist and scores into a double vector
public static void readFile(ArrayList<String> students,int numStu, FileIn file, double[]vector, double avg)
{
    for(int k=0; k<(numStu*2); k++)
    {
                    //odd numbers are the students
        if (k % 2 == 0)
            students.add(file.read());

        else
        {
            //code to read and add the numbers from one line together, and storing the added and averaged score
        }
    }
}


}
```

As you can see I'm missing the bottom part where im distributing the file elements into a double vector

my FileIn class looks like this:

```
private String myFileName;
private BufferedReader myFile;
public FileIn(String filename)
{
    myFileName = filename;
    try
    {
        myFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFileName));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{}
}

public String read()
{
    String myLine = new String();
    try
    {
        myLine = myFile.readLine();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{}
    return myLine;
}
}
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: @AdrianShum I want to know how to add the numbers from a line from the file, average them out, then store it into a double vector.

Comment: 1 - read the numbers from the line, 2 - find the average, 3 - store the average in the double vector

Comment: What's your problem? You dunno how to read a line from a file? or you dunno how to convert a string to an integer/double? or you don't know how to average multiple numbers? or you don't know how to "store" something into a "vector"?

Comment: @AdrianShum I don't know how to take the line of numbers and add them like they were separate numbers, not a String of numbers.

Comment: look into : String.split() and Double.parseDouble()

Comment: next time, please make your question 'to-point'.  Simply quoting a bunch of unrelated code and let other guess your problem is not going to help the answerers.  Learn to simplify the problem.  In your case, try to write a little piece of code that take a String with numbers in it and add them as double.  Even you failed to do so at last, show us what you have tried, so people know what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete the following piece of code, and you will know the answer to your own question once you finished it.

```
public class Foo {
  public static int main(String[] args) {
    String input = "10 15 20.5 70 40";

    // write code to convert the input string to doubles and sum them up
    double sum = ......;

    // answer should equals to 155.5
  }
}
```

Hints: `String.split()` and `Double.parseDouble()`, and make use of a for loop